# A database system for storing mobile device data?

Tags: database

I'm starting to build an app, a mobile device. Performance is quite important (as it is in anything else) and I'd like to maximize it.

The database will be used pretty often. I'm looking to access it through the QtSQL library of the C++ Qt library.

I have experience in MySQL, but don't think that's the right choice.

So I'm looking at:

- PostgreSQL
- sqlite?
- CouchDB?

The operating system is a stripped-down build of Ubuntu. Need regular CRUD as well as opportunity for optimization.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What's the O/S running on the mobile device? What database features do you want?

Comment: Ubuntu. And the regular CRUD stuff, with indexing and opportunity for optimiztion.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apple uses sqlite on the iPhone and iPod Touch, I would take a good look at that. I assume that they will have evaluated everything available to them at the time to get to this conclusion.

Since sqlite is FOSS and "endorsed" by a well-known vendor of mobile devices, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider Sybase [Ultralite](http://www.sybase.com/developer/mobile/sqlanywhere/ultralite)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new student developer, but it appears that SQLite might be the best bet to go.  Aside from being what seems to be the preferred iOS online database... it seems to have a lot of support with [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) and the upcoming [Windows Phone 7 Platform][2] (via C-sharp-sqllite).  Which seem to be the most dominating (or in the case of Windows Phone 7 - upcoming) platforms for most web development.  Blackberry and webOS doesn't seem to have an issue either.